# Add a separator line to the components list in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, separator

I have a setup script with a long list of optional components, and I would like to divide into groups so that the user can navigate it more easily. I can't find a way to add a separator line to the list of components, but I found this clumsy-looking workaround, using the Unicode em-dash

```
Name: "Separator"; Description: "————————————————————————————"; Flags: fixed
```

That produces a grayed-out box and a horizontal line. It isn't great, but maybe it's better than nothing. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is not bad.

The other options you have:

- Group related components under a "parent component".

  ```
  [Components]
  Name: "group1"; Description: "Group 1"
  Name: "group1\comp1"; Description: "Component 1"
  Name: "group1\comp2"; Description: "Component 2"
  Name: "group2"; Description: "Group 2"
  Name: "group2\comp3"; Description: "Component 3"
  Name: "group2\comp4"; Description: "Component 4"
  ```
- Completely re-implement the *Select Components* page using custom controls with your desired layout. Hide the components checklist box. Create your own controls. As the user modifies the selection using your custom controls, reflect the changes on the hidden checklist box. It's lot of work.